# How to manage mime types when downloading files with responseType = stream with Axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I got this simple function:

```
module.exports.getStream = (fileURL) => {

    return Axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: fileURL,
        responseType: 'stream',
    }).then(response => {
        return response.data;
    });

};
```

You give it an URL and it returns a stream. Now I'm taking that stream and passing it to another function that uploads the file elsewhere using form-data, that payload is made as follows:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", await getStream(URL));
```

All of that works, the stream is there and the uploading services receives it, BUT it responds saying that the `file` mime type **application/octet-stream** is not allowed and It can only be: application/pdf, application/acrobat, application/nappdf. Now that's fine, the uploading service is indeed made (by a third party) only to accept PDF files. Now the thing is, the stream I'm passing comes from a PDF file that has its content type set accordingly (application/pdf), as you can see here: https://highcrowd.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/user_documents_DEVELOPING/644a3bb7cd101f1dd47d6255-5b3aae09-bbf6-410f-8573-50a8c941f6ec.pdf

For some reason, the Axios client is setting the stream as application/octet-stream even if the server (S3) is responding with the correct content-type. Am I missing something?

To make matters more confusing, certain files downloaded with the same exact code generate a mime type stream with application/pdf instead of application/octet-stream

*EDIT: FormData is a NPM library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data*

Comment: What is `FormData` and how are you using it for the upload? The [DOM `FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) does appear not to support streams

Comment: @Bergi you are right, forgot to add that to my question, FormData is this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data

Comment: Thanks! I guess the relevant part from the docs is "*Form-Data can recognize and fetch all the required information from common types of streams (`fs.readStream`, `http.response` and mikeal's `request`), for some other types of streams you'd need to provide "file"-related information manually*". You'd probably have to read the source to find out how exactly it "recognises" the type from the argument and why works only sometimes for your axios response stream, but you could just overwrite the mime type (if you know it for sure or get it from the `response` headers)